# Within Eclipse, how to run Tomcat Maven plugin that modifies the context path

Tags: maven, tomcat, plugins

Inside Eclipse with m2 Maven plugin installed. I can run my webapp in Tomcat via Eclipse WTP using "Run on Server" command.

Now I want to modify the context-path via Maven, so I use the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <path>${contextpath-name}</path>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But then how do you exactly run this plugin inside Eclipse. Using Eclipse WTP always gives me the following URL - `http://localhost:8080/myapp`

I know I could run the plugin on a standalone Maven, but I want to know how to do it within Eclipse

Comment: Does your context path start with "/" ?

Comment: Do you have m2elipse plugin installed in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. For example, /mypath. I have m2eclipse installed.

Answer (score 10):

**Assumption**

I am assuming that you have already installed the plugins for Maven for eclipse.

**Installation**

While selecting the project in project explorer select Run --> Run As --> Maven Install

**Running Tomcat**

Go to Run --> Run Configurations..

Add new Maven Build

Name the Process, Select the Base directory that will be deployed as war

set the Goal --> **tomcat:run** *(this is a default goal for Tomcat)*

By following the steps you can deploy every thing via Eclipse.

Have fun. :)

Answer (score 0):

With Maven, it's very simple. Just add this property with the desired context path :

```
<properties>
   <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>put-the-context-here</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
</properties>
```